# Beamer table of contents jumps to the wrong slide

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, luatex, viewers, hyperlink

Consider the following `beamer` presentation, saved in a file named `Presentation.tex`.

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{My Title}
\author{Evan Aad}
\institute[Hogwarts]{Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry}
\date{\today}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Second Frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Third Frame}\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Second Frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Third Frame}\end{frame}

\section{Third Section}

\begin{frame}{First Frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Second Frame}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Third Frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When it is compiled from the command line via `arara Presentation`, a 13 page pdf file is produced as output. When I browse down to the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th slide (it doesn't matter which one), and I click the `Second Section` item, the pdf viewer displays the last two slides of the first section, and the top of the 1st slide of the second section, as the screenshot below shows.

[image: With pausesections]

This is contrary to my expectations that the viewer display the 1st slide of the second section fully at the top of the viewer display area.

If I remove the `pausesections` option from the `\tableofcontents` command (this command reveals the table of contents gradually over 3 slides corresponding to the 3 sections of the presentation), then the above scenario plays out as expected, as the following screenshot shows.

[image: Without pausesections]

I tested this with two pdf viewers: mac's native Preview, and Google's Chrome browser, and in both cases the same behavior occurred.

Why doesn't my original presentation behave as expected? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Is removing `\section*{Introduction}˙` an option? Without it links works as expected.

Comment: @Zarko: Not an option.

Comment: @Zarko: By the way, the document's structure follows the template `generic-ornate-15min-45min.en.tex` found in the `beamer/doc/solutions/generic-talks` folder mentioned in the beamer package manual.

Comment: Needs 3 compilations, very same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668376/tikz-fails-to-locate-a-beamer-slides-top-left-corner-in-the-presence-of-the-war

Comment: @StefanPinnow The problems raised in the two posts are completely different, but they had the same solution. If you consider this an indication of duplicate posts, then you can close this as a duplicate of the other.